# Best way to show "app not installed" feedback message after opening deep link?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, deep-linking

we're doing a web app that runs in mobile browsers (mainly Chrome, Firefox, the ones built-in in Android and Safari in iOS). It has a **link** that takes you to a **mobile app**. We don't own the mobile app, so we can't modify it in any way. We are only given the deep link like: `myapp://someotherstuff`.

The thing is that when I follow it, for example in Chrome for Google Pixel 4, I get this warning in the console:
[image]

Just for more info, in desktop I get this error:
[image]

I want to capture this error to show the user a  feedback message like: *"It seems that your app is not installed. You can download it from..."*.

### First, how I fire the navigation (different ways):

- With `window.open(deepLink, '_self')` ([example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuejs-vuex-starter-vpfmeg?file=deep-link.component.js)).
- **Manually** create a visible anchor tag with `href="deepLink"` (same [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuejs-vuex-starter-vpfmeg?file=deep-link.component.js)).
- **Programatically** create a hidden anchor tag on the fly with `href="deepLink"` (same [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuejs-vuex-starter-vpfmeg?file=deep-link.component.js)).

### Second, how I tried to capture the error (different ways):

- Wrap `window.open(...)` in a `try/catch` block. No result.
- **Listen** to errors thrown by the browser, of whatever type, with `window.onerror` (same [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuejs-vuex-starter-vpfmeg?file=deep-link.component.js)) and no result:

```
window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
    console.log('Error captured here');
}
```

- Use [**Chrome Intents**](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/multidevice/android/intents/). They work on Chrome but I'm not sure if they would work on non-Chrome or Android browsers like Safari. And it seems to me like an old feature from 2014 (perhaps I'm wrong).
- Can't use [**App Links**](https://blog.branch.io/technical-guide-to-android-app-links/) because they require changes in the server of a webpage that we don't own.

### My current workaround:

1. Manually or programatically click the link in the anchor tag
2. Set a timeout of 3 seconds. If in 3 seconds the page is still visible (with [`document.visibilityState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilityState)) it means that the browser could not open the app, so I show the message.

### Problems

False positives. What if the user changes the focus to another browser tab? My setTimeout would thing that, ok, the visibility of the page is `hidden`, so the app opened. And actually not.

### Question:

What's the best approach to show this *"app not installed"* feedback to the user? Do you know a better one than the described here?

Comment: There are meta tags you can add in your header that will provide a "Install this app!" banner on mobile devices, if it's not installed.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. It doesn't fit with the UX I want, but good to know.

Comment: On my side I wait for the `window.onblur` event and after a very short delay consider the app if not installed.